# JavaScript: How to wait for 3rd Party library to load before executing code & returning value

Tags: javascript

I need to wait to ensure a 3rd party library (**inJump**) has loaded before I execute my code. I've looked at a bunch of posts but I'm very new to this and I don't see how? Below is a basic example of what I need to accomplish.

```
function geoLoc () {
  //ensure/wait for "inJump" 3rd party library load
  var loc = inJump.getGeolocationData();
  return loc;
}

function mainFunc (v1,v2) {
  result = geoLoc();
  return result;
}

var myGeoLocation = mainFunc("val1","val2");
```

Comment: how are you attempting to load this library? by the way, `return result = geoLoc;` assigns the function `geoLoc` to the global variable `result` and returns it ... none of which actually RUNS that function - also `v1,v2` are never used, so not sure what your code is event pretending to do

Comment: You need to call `mainFunc()` and not `mainFunct()`. Also, in the function itself you need to `return geoLoc();` if you actually want to call the function and return its return value.

Comment: Sorry for the errors. The library and this code runs in a Tag Manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For newcomers to web development, here's a simpler explanation:

When using external tools like the "inJump" library, it's important to ensure they load completely before using them. Using a library prematurely can cause errors in your script. This is especially true for JavaScript, which often runs code asynchronously.

So, how do you check if a library is ready? A common method is to repeatedly check if a specific function or variable from the library is available. This is like repeatedly knocking on a door to see if someone's home.

For a practical approach, JavaScript offers a function called setInterval. It lets you run a function at set intervals. Using this, you can check regularly (e.g., every 100 milliseconds) if "inJump" or its components are ready. Once confirmed, you can safely run your dependent code.

```
function waitForInJump(callback) {
    // Check every 100ms to see if inJump is available
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        if (typeof inJump !== 'undefined' && typeof inJump.getGeolocationData === 'function') {
            clearInterval(interval);  // Stop checking once it's available
            callback();  // Execute the callback function
        }
    }, 100);
}

function geoLoc() {
    // Wait for "inJump" 3rd party library to load
    var loc;
    waitForInJump(function() {
        loc = inJump.getGeolocationData();
    });
return loc;
}

function mainFunc(v1, v2) {
    var result = geoLoc();
    return result;
}

var myGeoLocation = mainFunc("val1", "val2");
```